# Create keyboard shortcut for context menu item

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, evernote

Evernote Mac has a feature called "Copy Classic Note Link" that I constantly use, it only appears in context menu when you right click a note like this:

[image]

Although it has a shortcut `Option-C`, but that only take effect AFTER the context menu is shown, which means I still need an extra right click to use the feature.

I have tried to create a custom evernote shortcut in System `Preference > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts` but in vail. I suppose that approach only works for menu items, not context menu items.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you familiar with Applescript? Looking at Evernote's script library and the syntax of each link type, you should be able to bridge the gap by creating a script, putting it in your Evernote scripts folder, and assigning that a keyboard shortcut. I don't know that I have time to write the script and provide a full answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

Option-C doesn't seem to work anymore. There is no keyboard shortcut for 'Copy Classic Note Link' visible anymore in the contextual menu. Creating one in the System Preferences made the 'Copy Classic Note Link'-button disappear altogether. Maybe this is a recent change to Evernote.

Anyway, I figured out a workaround. It's not pretty, but it seems to do the trick.

To get this to work, you will need to use two tools: [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.de) and AppleScript.

BetterTouchTool can simulate a right click *without having to use a mouse or a trackpad*.

Although BetterTouchTool can simulate key presses as well, I couldn't get it to wait a fraction of a second between pressing and holding the alt key and pressing return. This meant that the return key was actually pressed *before* the 'Copy Classic Note Link'-button was visible. So I decided to use AppleScript instead.

First create this AppleScript (which I named Alt Return.scpt - just make sure you reference the right script in BetterTouchTool) and store it somewhere.

```
tell application "Evernote"
    tell application "System Events"
        key down option
        delay 0.2
        keystroke "c"
        delay 0.2
        key code 36 -- press return
        key up option
    end tell
end tell
```

Then create this workflow in BetterTouchTool:

- Decide what keyboard shortcut you want to use
- Make a keyboard shortcut with an 'assigned action' - Right Click
- Next: 'Attach additional action' - Open Application/File/AppleScript…
- Link to the AppleScript you just created

I am not allowed to post a picture of this workflow (yet) as I just created my account. Hope this helps somebody!